# Is there a Net Send or Msg.exe equivalent for IOS and other mobile platorms?

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, webos

I think the subject says it all.  I'm just wondering if there are messaging apps that run by default on iOS, Andriod, Blackberry, WebOS etc, which work somewhat similarly to netsend.  I'm trying to communicate with various mobile devices on the same wireless LAN without installing a custom app on each one.  In browser app would work as well, but not quite what I"m looking for.  I want to essentially be able to broadcast a message to devices on my LAN.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you count SMS, or as you point out, something browser-based, neither of which really work like net send.

Comment: Just curious, how would SMS work over WiFi, i.e. in a closed network (being able to only message within the local network)?

Comment: It wouldn't really. That's what I'm saying. Same with browser really, unless you have a local server, it's not going to work.

Comment: I could add a local server, just no connection to the internet or to cell phone services

Comment: Actually, just found out, you can't do SMS without a custom app in a closed wifi network.  Alas, Javascript & web browser based messaging it is!